# Is it equivalent use "copy" or "append" slice type in golang

Tags: go, slice

```golang
    a := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    // Method: 1
    b := make([]byte, len(a))
    copy(b, a)
    // Method: 2
    c := append([]byte(nil), a...)
```

Q: Is the method 2 more concise and efficient than method 1?

Q: Whether mode 2 and mode 1 are equivalent, both are deep copy?

thank you for your help

Comment: They are equivalent. Method 2 will allocate and copy. Both are shallow copies.

Comment: Wether 1 or to is more "efficient" depends on _your_ definition of "efficient" which even might be different under different circumstances.

Comment: My understanding is that method 1 will zero the memory first, and method 2 may apply for a larger space

Comment: Method 2 also zeros the memory first (there is no un-zeroed memory in Go) and wether 2 allocates more space or not is an unspecified implementation detail.

Answer (score 7):

Method 1 is more precise - as it allocates exactly the slice size it needs & fills it.

Method 2's append will allocate a slice of capacity (depending probably on your architecture) in units of 8. So those 3 initial items will be copied to a backing array of size 8:

https://go.dev/play/p/C2nPQFflsM2

Answer (score 1):

You can use both methods if you fix the implementation of the second method.

```
// Method 1
b := make([]byte, len(a))
copy(b, a)

// Method 2
c := make([]byte, 0, len(a))
c = append(c, a...)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rkMmIsSaHVW